# Flex Getting Error: Error #2154: The NetStream Object is invalid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe

I'm trying to develop flex app using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6, small multicast conferencing solution. But I have lots of troubles to run this app. Basically I run app in safari (via flash builder), everything work fine, just I expected. I export app and run it again, just like before works great (in browser on file:// .... /multicast.html).

Problem occurs when I try to run it on any server. Like, on python -

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

or rails webrick or any another.

if I open a browser and type localhost:8080/multicast.html, it will run app but as3 throw an exception with this:

```
Error: Error #2154: The NetStream Object is invalid.  This may be due to a failed     NetConnection.
    at flash.net::NetStream/invoke()
    at flash.net::NetStream/attachCamera()
    at multicast/setupStream()
    at multicast/netStatus()
```

source: http://pastebin.com/wyhzXveC

I decided to completely uninstall chrome and install again to avoid flash debugger, which is installed in safari. So far, no luck.

Any suggestions, tips, anything?
Thanks!

Comment: What is coming back from the connection? eg. this line `writeText(event.info.code);` - Though I suppose it has to be success for your netStream to get created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found it!** I did not realize, that `stream.attachCamera(cam);` needs to wait after netStream will be successfully connected to a server.

Thanks @LDMediaServices!